# Get size of a get request with axios

Tags: node.js, axios, request

I want to track the size of all my requests to display traffic but the Content-Length header is missing. This is probably caused by the Transfer-Encoding header being set to chunked and I have no Idea how to change this. My goal is to get the complete size of a request including headers and all that stuff.

```
axios.get("https://discord.com/api/v9/experiments", { 
    headers: {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
        "x-accept-encoding": "gzip",
        "Content-Encoding": "gzip"
    }
}).then((res) => log the size of the whole request)
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?